# Including lib in arm-elf cross compile: undefined reference

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

So, I'm trying to build a small program using libmodbus using an arm-elf cross compiler, and I keep getting undefined reference errors for libmodbus even though it is built for the cross compiler and in the lib folder.

I have already built libmodbus

```
./configure --host=arm-elf --prefix=/usr/local/arm-elf
make && make install
```

Then, I wrote my program, making sure to include the modbus header

```
#include <modbus/modbus.h>
```

and compiled it

```
arm-elf-gcc  -o modbus_read_register  -Wl,-elf2flt -v -lmodbus modbus_read_register.c
```

but it always fails at, what I think, is the linking phase

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/arm-elf/2.95.3/collect2 -X -o modbus_read_register /usr/local/arm-elf/lib/crt0.o -L/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/arm-elf/2.95.3 -L/usr/local/arm-elf/lib -elf2flt -lmodbus /tmp/cc000Bvc.o -lgcc -lc -lgcc
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0x88): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_new_tcp'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0x98): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_connect'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0xb0): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_strerror'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0xcc): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_free'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0x11c): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_read_registers'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0x13c): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_strerror'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0x1cc): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_close'
modbus_read_register.elf2flt(.text+0x1d4): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `modbus_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [modbus_read_register] Error 1
```

I can't figure out why the linker isn't working, since the libmodbus.a file is at the correct path and is being provided in the args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your libmodbus package is installed in the location provided by prefix, that is in

> --prefix=**/usr/local/arm-elf**

You should specify this path when compiling your program **modbus_read_register.c**

> arm-elf-gcc  -o modbus_read_register  -Wl,-elf2flt -v -lmodbus modbus_read_register.c 
>   **-L/usr/local/arm-elf/lib**

Here -L option will redirect your linker to search for the files in the specified directory